# Size for Flash program on a website?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am developing a flash as2 game. I want to put it on a website, and I would like it to

1. Fit the whole screen.
2. Not have to scroll up, down, left or right.

What size would you recommend I put the flash as2 game to?
EG. 200px by 200px.

And to keep in mind (Not intending to advertise) my game will look something like agar.io.

To make it easy for me, please answer in Inches, Centimeters, Pixels, Millimeters or points.

Comment: Why do you want to set the size. Wouldn't it be easier to set it to 100% width and height in html and use stage.width and stage.height in your code?

Comment: @Bart because I am horrible at programming and I don't know how to do that :) post a full answer please

Comment: Like this(first hit from google for me): http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_autofit.html

Answer (score 0):

Built it to scale and then set the height and width as parameters in the HTML declaration.  Have Flash check the passed params and assign default values if none are passed.  Without knowing what your game is, I can't really recommend a default size.  However, if you are worried about accessibility, I would not go higher than 800 px in any one dimension.  Remember though, you want to set the size percentage in the HTML, so all you really need to worry about is the X:Y proportion.  Let the page designer worry about the proper sizing percent.